# How to stop Cloth Simulation Sticking to Collision Object

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am animating my character pushing through theatre curtains, but no matter what I do I can't seem to stop the curtain sticking to the collision object.

[image: Cloth Sim sticking to collision object]

What should happen is the impulse from the collision object surrounding the umbrella should give some impetus to the curtain fabric which then should fall naturally behind my character (with some tweaks).

What is happening is that the cloth tracks the position of the collision object exactly.

I have tried many settings:

- Denim; Quality steps 12, Vertex Mass up to 20 kg, Air Viscosity up to 10, Tension/Comp/Shear up to 80, Bending up to 40.
- Damping likewise increasing up to 50 and Bending to 5.
- Self collisions on, distance 0.0015
- On the collision object I have damping up to 0.7 and friction down to 0.

These more heavy duty settings improve it, but they all are sticking to the collision object after the inital impetus. Is there a way to maybe turn off the collision object at some point perhaps?

Comment: there are several ways to do that. But since you didn't show us your settings now (and a lot of settings depend on each other) and it is a complex calculation which Blender does, we can only "make proposals" which might or might not help you. So if you want precise help, you should provide your blend file. One way e.g. is to make a simple "proxy" object of your rigged body so that the curtain calculation is easier for Blender and might not stick to it. And of course turn off or lower the friction as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make it plain enough, but there is only a simple collision object. You can see it in the image - it is a simple cylinder enclosing the umbrella. The cloth is sticking to that. I listed my settings above - starting with the default denim and trying multiple settings up to those I have listed. Any not mentioned are left at default.

Comment: Currently, my solution is to parent the cylinder via the object constraint and animate its influence to 0 at the right moment and then animate the cylinder going to roughly the right position for the curtain. It's not very pretty. There must be a way for the collision influence to be turned off, or some setting that prevents the cloth from "sticking" to the collision object.

Comment: Ok - well with further experimentation, using a cube (as collision object) instead of a cylinder yields much better results.